# Managing Timezone in magento

Tags: magento, timezone

How to manage timezone in magento at the time of product creation, in frontend i am filtering products by time,but problem is that client wants to show products creation time depend on user's timezone ? for example i am adding a product in admin area it shows 12.21pm but at the same time customer viewing this product from other country it should displays current time according to user's time zone, how can we do that?
please help me to get out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $time_zone = $session->getCustomer()->getTimezone();
        $timeoffset = Mage::getModel('core/date')->calculateOffset($time_zone);
        $timeoffset = $timeoffset - Mage::getModel('core/date')->getGmtOffset($time_zone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific about how you are generating the date and how you wish it to be displayed...

Here is a general approach:

In your template code place a span with a class around your time values. These time strings can be formatted with lots of options including the timezone in your php code.

Place javascript where appropriate: either in the header (onload function), in the footer or inline with your view.phtml.

In your javascript use the Prototype library to iterate over the time spans, e.g.:

```
$$('yourdateclass').each(function() {
//
});
```

On each of those elements convert the time with Date.parse() to a date object. Then use getTimezoneOffset to account for the visitors location, add/subtract accordingly and then update the element inner html to your preferred way of showing the time/date.